# Exclude a ListView Group when sorting

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, listview

I have a ListView (WinForms) called "mainListView" in which I show the files and folders of the current path. Depending on the extension of each file I put them in different groups. I also have columns that sort the mainListView when the user click on them.

Recently I have added a group which behavior may be a bit different than the others, so the problem comes when the user click in a column trying to sort the items in the list, the new group becomes a disaster an is disordered. There are some elements in this group without information in some columns, so if you sort by this columns this disorder occurs which is normal so I just want to exclude this group for being sorted.

I was wondering if there is **some way to exclude this group for being sorted when a column is clicked**. Or if independently of which column is clicked I could apply a different sorting criteria for this group. I've been trying lots of things and looking for an answer and I think this is not going to be possible but I won't give up without asking as least.

My sorting code at the moment:
In DisplayProperties I store some user configurations to be remembered when the program is loaded again. So basically:

***DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSortAsc*** contains the sort order: Ascending or Descending.
***DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnsSaved[]*** contains a list of strings with the identification of each column in mainListView.

```
private void mainListView_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnsSaved[e.Column] == DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSort)
    {
        if (DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSortAsc == SortOrder.Ascending)
            DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSortAsc = SortOrder.Descending;
        if (DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSortAsc == SortOrder.Descending)
            DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSortAsc = SortOrder.Ascending;
    }
    else DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSort = DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnsSaved[e.Column];

    mainListView.ListViewItemSorter = Sorter;

    if (!(mainListView.ListViewItemSorter is ListViewSorter))
        return;

    Sorter = (ListViewSorter)mainListView.ListViewItemSorter;

    if (Sorter.LastSort == e.Column)
    {
        if (mainListView.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
            mainListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
        else
            mainListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
    }
    else
        mainListView.Sorting = DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSortAsc;

    Sorter.ByColumn = e.Column;
    DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSortAsc = mainListView.Sorting;
    DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnSort = DisplayProperties.mainListViewColumnsSaved[e.Column];
    mainListView.Sort();
}
```

Comment: Is this winforms / wpf / webforms? We're going to need a bit more information.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is using a winforms ListView. Is something complicated to explain but basically what I am looking for is some way to sort without affecting an specific group of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. It was more simple than what I though. 
I just added some restrictions in the IComparer class for sorting my ListView.
Basically I don't do nothing if the object to Compare is inside the group of items called "Multi", which is the group of items I didn't want to affect when sorting by clicking in the columns.

I let you my piece of code for the IComparer here in case it is useful for someone with a similar problem.

```
public class ListViewSorter : IComparer
        {
            public int ByColumn { get; set; }

            public int LastSort { get; set; }

            public int Compare(object o1, object o2)
            {
                if (!(o1 is ListViewItem) || o1 is ListViewGroup)
                    return (0);
                if (!(o2 is ListViewItem) || o2 is ListViewGroup)
                    return (0);

                var itm = (ListViewItem)o1;
                if (itm.Group.Header.Contains("Multi"))
                    return (0);

                itm = (ListViewItem)o2;
                if (itm.Group.Header.Contains("Multi"))
                    return (0);

                var lvi1 = (ListViewItem)o2;
                string str1 = "";
                if (lvi1.SubItems.Count > ByColumn)
                    str1 = lvi1.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;

                var lvi2 = (ListViewItem)o1;
                string str2 = "";
                if (lvi2.SubItems.Count > ByColumn)
                    str2 = lvi2.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;

                int result;

                string a, b;
                if (lvi1.ListView.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    a = str1;
                    b = str2;
                }
                else
                {
                    a = str2;
                    b = str1;
                }

                DateTime dateTimeA;
                DateTime dateTimeB;
                double doubleA;
                double doubleB;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(a, out dateTimeA)
                  && DateTime.TryParse(b, out dateTimeB))
                {
                    result = DateTime.Compare(dateTimeA, dateTimeB);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (double.TryParse(a, out doubleA)
                      && double.TryParse(b, out doubleB))
                    {
                        result = doubleA.CompareTo(doubleB);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = String.Compare(a, b);
                    }
                }

                LastSort = ByColumn;

                return (result);
            }
        }
```